# Calculate Double accurately

Tags: swift

How to calculate doubles accurately in Swift?
I try it on Swift playground, and 10.0 - 0.2 won't be 9.8.
How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Read this, it's enlightening: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: It is a (well-known) fact that binary floating point numbers cannot represent all values exactly. [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) is an enlightening thread around that issue.

Comment: And of course: ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: @EricD. I know Floating-Point Arithmetic, but we have library like https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/ in Javascript to solve these problems. Is there similar thing in Swift?

Comment: @Howard: NSDecimalNumber.

Comment: @MartinR http://i.imgur.com/AxsiXgU.png Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *round*.
So for your example this should work:

```
let x = 10.0 - 0.2
let y = Double(round(100*x)/100)
```

If you want more accuracy multiply and divide for example by 1000 or 10000 and so on.